# Swift dependency injection by passing class as a function parameter to call a class method

Tags: swift, class, types, dependency-injection

I may be approaching this the wrong way, but I would like to introduce dependency injection for unit testing purposes, and in order to do so I would need to pass a class as a parameter. In somewhat of a pseudo code it should look like this:

```
protocol LocalSavingProtocol {
    static func saveDataLocally()
}

class ProductionClass: LocalSavingProtocol {
    static func saveDataLocally() {
        print("actually save data")
    }
}

class TestClass: LocalSavingProtocol {
    static func saveDataLocally() {
        print("test saving data")
    }
}

func saveEverywhere(injecting localSavingClass: LocalSavingProtocol = ProductionClass) {
    localSavingClass.saveDataLocally()
}

//production code
saveEverywhere()

//test
saveEverywhere(injecting: TestClass)
```

Obviously this does not work, and as much as I tried playing around with passing `.Type` or `.self`, changing the `saveEverywhere` function to

```
saveEverywhere<T: LocalSavingProtocol>(injecting localSavingClass: T)
```

and so on, nothing has worked.

The goal is to have a system such that:

1. I can inject a class when testing the code
2. I don't have to inject the class in production code (i.e. there is a default)
3. I can call a class method on the injected class

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable to your case, but if you pass a type, you won't be able to use instance methods. If you were using type methods (aka class func and static func in the protocol) that should work and you'd be able to use a "mock" type in your unit tests

Comment: Thanks Giorgio, not sure what you mean by the case that should work. I forgot to add the `static` labels, but it is of course supposed to include them. I just have no idea how to make it work in the form it is now.

Comment: see my answer, just run it right now in a playground and works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protocol LocalSavingProtocol {
    static func saveDataLocally()
}

class ProductionClass: LocalSavingProtocol {
    class func saveDataLocally() {
        print("actually save data")
    }
}

class TestClass: LocalSavingProtocol {
    class func saveDataLocally() {
        print("test saving data")
    }
}

func saveEverywhere(injecting localSavingClass: LocalSavingProtocol.Type = ProductionClass.self) {
    localSavingClass.saveDataLocally()
}

//production code
saveEverywhere()

//test
saveEverywhere(injecting: TestClass.self)
```

Answer (score -1):

Dependency injection does not involve passing in a class, it injects an object that something else can depend on, hence the word *dependency*. The reason this is useful for unit testing purposes is that you can encapsulate code into that separate object.

You are trying to access an instance method from a type. Dependency injection does not require a class type to be passed in. Pass in an object instead:

```
saveEverywhere(injecting: TestClass())
```

For the default value, use an object as well:

```
func saveEverywhere(injecting localSavingClass: LocalSavingProtocol = ProductionClass()) {
```

Note the `()` in both examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the issue is that I need to call an instance method, so passing an object isn't very useful, as I need to pass the class in order to call the method. I notice that my question was missing the `static` identifiers, I have now fixed that. The only was I found so far to get around this is to inject a closure itself rather than the dependency, so that ProductionClass.saveDataLocally is the default but when testing I may pass TestClass.saveDataLocally.